# How does consul KV consistency works in regards to updating the same key

Tags: consul, consul-kv

If given a consul KV key `a/key`, where there are multiple agent server instances running, what happens if:

Two requests A (set value to `val-a`) and B (set value to `val-b`) are made to the [create key endpoint](https://www.consul.io/api/kv#create-update-key) **without** making use of the parameters `cas` or `acquire` in order to update the **same** key `a/key`:

- If A and B are made in parallel can the key's value become corrupted?
- Or if A comes slightly before B can the final value still become `val-a`?

Answer (score 0):

The data will not be corrupted if Consul receives two write requests at the same time. The write requests would be processed serially by the leader, so the value of `a/key` would become either `val-a` or `val-b`, whichever is processed last.

You can find details on how Consul writes data in Consul's [Consensus Protocol](https://www.consul.io/docs/architecture/consensus) documentation.